# Deleting a file from /dev

Tags: devices

I am new to attempting to use the code for everything, and for once i don't have root permission on my user account as a back up.
I wasn't focussing while making an Iso with genisoimage and created it in the /dev system, which is were i had changed directory to earlier.
How do i go about deleting the iso I created from that file system?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Stephen

Comment: /dev is a temporary / dynamic filesystem. The file you created there should not survive a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
sudo rm /dev/yourfile
```

Only do this on files created by you. If you are going to delete `/dev/null` for example, things tend to break.